# How to infer function return type based on an function array argument?

Tags: typescript, types

Given a plain JS function that takes in an array of callbacks (that each returns an object), and then returns their combined output:

```ts
export const applyCallback = (callbacks) => {
  return callbacks.reduce((acc, callback) => { ...acc, ...callback() }, {});
}
```

How would one appropriately type this using TypeScript to infer the return type of `applyCallback`? Although I am aware of `ReturnType`, it applies to a single function, meanwhile here I would want to get a `ReturnType` of each callback and create a union of their return types.

Comment: I guess each callback can return a different object. Is it correct?

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka Yes that's correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with some overloads:

```js
type Fn = () => object

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;


function applyCallback<R extends Fn, U extends ReadonlyArray<R>>(...callbacks: U): UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<U[number]>>;
function applyCallback(...callbacks: Fn[]) {
  return callbacks.reduce((acc, callback) => {
    return { ...acc, ...callback() }
  }, {});
}


const result = applyCallback(
  () => ({ age: 42 }),
  () => ({ name: 'John' })
); // {age:42} & {name:'John'}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIBiA7eBeeAKAlOgfPAPYBGAVrAMbiigD0t8FATrACYCW4AzvAOaGwe4QvAAW4cNC4Auel3ABDCgGtCAN1hMAZgBtCAdwB0FQgFtaC2gFYADAGYA7FYBMADgBsEGAgCqydoTIACqEAJLI4JpclOAByAA8PgQYmD7wsAAekcisPArIkPAA-FjK0vA%20uGgEaoTsrPDlyLAaTLiZ2blYoPDwZfDsyFqa8KGgVTV1rD3FozNNLZoA3DRgIFoArshUcfAK0NA6kADCCjo6xErK8QBK6VmwOTwoADQV9508N7AKrIFHAEEmEwFJBbng8JhDNCKGcLlcZBVsOU-HEQuFIkxojtArdYOANkxgt5EgBtZAbUzETQAXQhK3WWxxqH2hxOcMuKihMI5CPKKFJNNwAG8ZiwCUTGLyVFxDCxWBsKLBMJglBQ3rDzpzlBN4KKQL1euLCahhfBoYY1W8LZr4VzcABfGYOt7Ch3YBlOtagEzIeTwFhcDY6cDoPYHI6nLVXTAzHD4LBmhS8WDlAAszng7pecd1mDNyAUplT8AA5AApQiiZClrPYcZLeD0PXJ1MZh3wABkesLxekFarNYdQA)

It is hard to narrow the initial value of reduce for TypeScript. Most of the type people are using type assertion `as`, but in this case type assertion does not help so I decided to use overloading.

You can find more information about typing callbacks in my [blog](https://catchts.com/callbacks)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Thanks for linking to the other SO thread too, as it lead to me to relevant docs for Typescript to understand what's going on.

Comment: https://catchts.com/callbacks here you can find more info

Answer (score 1):

To address the "in this case type assertion does not help" from the [captain-yossarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67243111/11407695) (completely fine otherwise): it is not necessary to return an intersection of objects and entirely possible to build up the desired object with the help of exactly the `as` assertion.

What's more, if one is content with the returned type only having *optional* properties, the assertion can be avoided entirely (but due to how the `reduce` method signature is typed, it is nigh impossible to ensure the compiler that it is safe to jump from an empty object to a fully populated one).

With the help of some [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) and mapped types, the task becomes fairly trivial<sup>0</sup>.

```ts
type AnyFunc = (...args:any[]) => any;

function applyCallback<T extends AnyFunc[]>(callbacks: T) {
  return callbacks.reduce((acc, callback) => {
    return { ...acc, ...callback() }
  }, {} as { [ P in ReturnType<T[number]> as keyof P ] : P[keyof P] });
}


const result = applyCallback([
  () => ({ age: 42 }),
  () => ({ name: 'John' })
]); /* { age: number; name: string; } */
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAYgVzgYygXigCgHQECGATgOYDOAXIQgNoC6AlFgHxQ0gDcAsAFB8AzVGmABLAPZx2YMABsQAYUKzZAI0JoA1gB4AKlAgAPYBDgATcrAQp0DFjjTK1GzVSi7mAbz5QoxCMDIxFKOKupa5Hj%20ZshoEDg4GmgANFChzlrMmGzevL6%20-oHBUJ5QBHhJqeXp4Zo4zAC%20PlANqZ4N7JaltFAAClCiUgBKAUFwuuAQerRwyAC2qhDE9GyElpoQIOICfVD0UJR9tBtbO737DYw8vE38d2iS5MB%20EOTIss-YhDLySmEuOFozXqrFwpUIpAghwALAAmFqMZLArJsHClOCEOZQqAAcgAUuIABZwHEIvhMThQAD0VJK7EhlDhqQxWMo%20KJJJaQA)

---

<sup>0</sup> Note that the `applyCallback` signature follows the one in the question that accepts a single function array instead of rest parameters.